# Can't find issue in simple js for-loop

Tags: javascript

I am trying out javascript for (more-or-less) the first time and find myself completely baffled by the following .js script.

```
var pair = newArray();
var id = newArray();
var pairs = 2;

function newGame(){

    var randomid = 0;

    alert("newGame() called!");

    // Sets a specific part of the image sprite to each pair[].
    for (var i=0 ;i < pairs; i++){
        alert("For loop started!");
        pair[i] = "url(Cardfront.jpg) -"+100 * Math.floor((Math.random()*13)+0)+"px -"+200 * Math.floor((Math.random()*4)+0)+"px";
        // For every pair, assigns a part of the image sprite to two id[]-s.
        alert("Pair " + i + "is " + pair[i]);
        for(var j=0; j < 2; j++) {
            //the range of possible id-s the total number of cards - double the amount of pairs.
            randomid = Math.floor((Math.random()*pairs*2)+0);
            if (id[randomid] === null){
                id[randomid] = pair[i];
                alert("ID " + randomid + "is " + id[randomid]);
            }
            else j--;
        }
    }

    alert("This is called after the for loop!");
}
```

When I call newGame() through a button, I receive the "newGame() called!" and then "This is called after the for loop!" alerts, then nothing.

I've spent a while googling and poking around trying to figure this out, but I'm at the end of my wits, it seems.

Comment: What is `newArray()`? If you're trying to instantiate an array, just use `var pair = [];`

Comment: I assume it is an array. In any case, as long as the first alert gets called, it should work. I see nothing wrong with it. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/Xhzfh/ is this really exactly the same code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `newArray()` to `new Array()` I believe that is what is causing your error sir.

Good luck!

EDIT: To fix the other error I found you have the following:

```
if (id[randomid] === null) {
```

with 3 `=` sign. Change it to just two:

```
if (id[randomid] == null) {
```

and it should work the way you expect it to.
Unless you are really trying to use the strict comparisson operator, then there is something else bugging your code.

Comment: There will bi an issue with the `j--` in the second loop too, but this should be the problem,
I'm wondering though why the first alert fires, if `newArray` is undefined, it should throw an expception at line 0

Comment: Oh. Oooooooh. Welp, face, meet palm. :P

Comment: @Glutamat yes I noticed there is another error that will make freeze the browser inside the loop.

Comment: Yes, I actually checked if I declared my arrays correctly and somehow came to the conclusion I did. Changing it to new Array() fixed it, thanks! (still throws an exeption, but I guess i can continue to debug it now)

Comment: The new Array() is certainly an issue, but considering the first alert fires, it makes no sense :/ anyone have an idea what causes that?

Comment: That `alert` is in the `newGame()` function which probably is called on button click or something...

Comment: @HanletEscaño You're also right that the strict comparison there needed to be removed. Which is a bit odd, I only added that because a tutorial said that I should always use strict comparison when comparing to null values. Thank you for the help, kind sir.

Answer (score 1):

In this piece of code:

```
if (id[randomid] === null){
    id[randomid] = pair[i];
    alert("ID " + randomid + "is " + id[randomid]);
}
else j--;
```

You can't mix the `if/else` shorthand:

```
if(something)
    //Do X
else
    //Do y
```

With it's bracket notation:

```
if(something){
    //Do X
} else {
    //Do y
}
```

So, put brackets around your `else`:

```
if (id[randomid] === null){
    id[randomid] = pair[i];
    alert("ID " + randomid + "is " + id[randomid]);
} else {
    j--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The for loop should read:</strike>

```
for (var i=0; i<pairs.length; i++) {
   ...
}
```

`pairs` is being coerced into a numeric value (zero in this case), so the first comparison (`i<pairs`) will be the same as `0<0` which will never true.

:-(

Comment: It is, but you need to compare `i` to its `length`, not to the object itself (which is non-sensical).

Comment: that sort of comparison (`$i < @array`) is OK in Perl, but not in JavaScript.

Comment: also, assuming no other code outside your example, you still have a few other problems.

Comment: `var pairs = 2;` its definitely an Integer not an array

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. Oops :-)

Comment: You do kind of point out that having two things so similarly named is somewhat of a bad idea. I changed "pairs" to "totalpairs" to better reflect it's function.